# if $\boldsymbol{f(x)}$ is not convergent, can $\boldsymbol{f(x)}$ be separated in limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ and $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then can it be expressed as $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)\lim_{x\to0}h(x)$?

Comment: Not in general. What's your actual aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Suppose, for instance, that $g(x)=x$ and that $h(x)=2+\sin(x)$. Then $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, but the limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: how about lim (1/x+lnx)=lim(1/x)lim(1+xlnx)? if it's possible, what is the reason?

Comment: @YJ15 In this case, the LHS is $+\infty$, whereas the RHS is an indetermination ($0\times(+\infty)$).

Comment: is it possible as x goes to 0+?

Comment: @YJ15 No, for the same reason.